# When I press OK my input dialogue box keeps re-appearing

Tags: java, user-interface

I am making an Outliner App where you can Add nodes and edit them as a kind of to-do list however when I add a node and press "OK" the input box will re-appear and I cannot find the issue so some help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to use a boolean way already and managed to fix the "cancel" button however the OK button and X button in the top right still make the box re-appear

Controller class:

```
public class OutlinerController implements ActionListener {

    private OutlinerModel model;
    private OutlinerView view;

    public OutlinerController(OutlinerModel model, OutlinerView view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        // Register this controller as the listener for the buttons in the view
        view.addButtonListener(this);
        view.addEditButtonListener(this);
        view.addDeleteButtonListener(this);
        view.addCompleteButtonListener(this);
        view.addSearchButtonListener(this);
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) view.getTree().getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    if (e.getSource() == view.getAddButton()) {
        boolean adding = true;
        while (adding) {
            // Add a new node to the selected node 
            String nodeName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter node name:");
            if (nodeName == null) { // Cancel button pressed
                adding = false;
            } else if (nodeName.trim().equals("")) { // Empty name entered
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(view.getTree(), "Node name cannot be empty.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeName);
                model.getTreeModel().insertNodeInto(newNode, selectedNode, selectedNode.getChildCount());
                // Expand the selected node to show the newly added node 
                view.getTree().expandPath(new TreePath(selectedNode.getPath()));
            }
        }
    } if (e.getSource() == view.getEditButton()) {
        // Edit the selected node's name 
        String nodeName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new node name:");
        selectedNode.setUserObject(nodeName);
        model.getTreeModel().nodeChanged(selectedNode);
    }  if (e.getSource() == view.getDeleteButton()) {
        // Remove the selected node from the JTree 
        model.getTreeModel().removeNodeFromParent(selectedNode);
    }  if (e.getSource() == view.getCompleteButton()) {
        // Mark the selected node as complete 
        selectedNode.setUserObject(selectedNode.getUserObject() + " [Complete]");
        model.getTreeModel().nodeChanged(selectedNode);
    }  if (e.getSource() == view.getSearchButton()) {
        // Get the search term from the user 
        String searchTerm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter search term:");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode searchResult = searchNode(model.getRoot(), searchTerm);
        // If a node is found with the given search term, select and scroll to that node in the JTree 
        if (searchResult != null) {
            TreePath path = new TreePath(searchResult.getPath());
            view.getTree().setSelectionPath(path);
            view.getTree().scrollPathToVisible(path);
        } else {
            // If no node is found with the given search term, show a message to the user 
           view.displayErrorMessage("No node found with the given search term");
        }
    }
}

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode searchNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, String searchTerm) {
        // Check if the current node matches the search term 
        if (node.getUserObject().toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
            return node;
        }
        // Recursively search the child nodes of the current node 
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getChildAt(i);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode result = searchNode(childNode, searchTerm);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }

        // If no node is found with the given search term, return null 
        return null;

    }
        private void searchNode(String searchString) {
        // Get the root of the JTree 
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) view.getTree().getModel().getRoot();

        // Traverse the JTree and find nodes that match the search string 
        searchNodeHelper(searchString, rootNode);
    }

    private void searchNodeHelper(String searchString, DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {

        // Get the user object of the node and convert it to lowercase 
        String nodeString = node.getUserObject().toString().toLowerCase();

        // Check if the node string contains the search string 
        if (nodeString.contains(searchString)) {

            // If the node string contains the search string, expand its path and highlight it 
            TreePath path = new TreePath(node.getPath());
            view.getTree().expandPath(path);
            view.getTree().setSelectionPath(path);
            return;

        }

        // If the node string does not contain the search string, recursively check its children 
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getChildAt(i);
            searchNodeHelper(searchString, childNode);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A `while (true)` loop is useful when creating linear console apps, but is a  very bad idea when creating event-driven GUI apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue might be with the while loop in the actionPerformed method for adding a new node. The loop will continue to run as long as adding is true. In the case where the user clicks the "OK" button in the input dialog, adding is not explicitly set to false, so the loop will continue to run.

One solution would be to add a break statement after the DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeName); line in the if statement. This will exit the loop once a new node has been successfully added.

Comment: Yeah I just added a break and now the app is working seamlessly, thank you brother